# Don't know how to build task 'db:seed_fu'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have just added the [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) gem to my app for seeding my test-database:

```
group :test do
  gem 'seed-fu'
end
```

I made a custom rake task (in `/lib/tasks/db.rake`) for seeding **only** my test-database:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "seed_fu only in test-database"
  task seed_fu_test: :environment do
    Rails.env = 'test'
    puts "Seeding will be made in test-base ONLY!"
    Rake::Task["db:seed_fu"].execute
  end

end
```

If I do `rake -T | grep seed` then my new custom-made task is shown amongst other seed-tasks:

```
rake db:seed                            # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:seed_fu                         # Loads seed data for the current environment
rake db:seed_fu_test                    # seed_fu only in test-database
```

Now when I do `rake db:seed_fu_test` I get

> rake aborted!
>
> Don't know how to build task 'db:seed_fu'

**But** when I do

```
rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV='test'
```

then seed_fu seeds my test-database well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out- the problem was in my Gemfile. Because I added the seed-fu gem into `test`-group then in `development`-environment, which was my default for running also the `rake db:seed_fu_test` task, the seed_fu gem was not seen.

Therefore when moving `gem 'seed-fu'` line into my `:development`-group in Gemfile, the problem was solved.